# Why does epoll use a combination of the file descriptor number and the open file description to distinguish the registered file descriptors?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, epoll

In epoll(7):

> 0. What is the key used to distinguish the file descriptors registered in an interest list?
>    The key is the combination of the file descriptor number and the open file description (also known as an "open file handle", the kernel's internal representation of an open file).

Epoll uses `struct epoll_filefd` to distinguish items in interest list, and in `fs/eventpoll.c`:

```
/* Compare RB tree keys */
static inline int ep_cmp_ffd(struct epoll_filefd *p1,
                 struct epoll_filefd *p2)
{
    return (p1->file > p2->file ? +1:
            (p1->file < p2->file ? -1 : p1->fd - p2->fd));
}
```

It seems that Epoll compares the `struct file` pointer first, then the fd number. Why not just use the fd number, since applications can only do epoll calls on a fd number?

Comment: Because from the system's point of view, the `->file` is the *primary key*, referring to the system file table. The `->fd` field makes only sense in user space. While updating the tree (or for sending notifications) the system only knows the `->file` member.

Comment: Because multiple file descriptors can point to the same file description. Go on and read the Q1 and A1 after Q0 and A0 in that manpage.